# Whats is a RESTful way to get resources from all children?

Tags: rest, api

Suppose I have the following api where vin is a Vehicle Identification Number and belongs to a single car.

```
GET /fleets/123/cars/55/vin
GET /fleets/123/cars/55/history
```

And I want to get all the vins for all the cars for a fleet. Which would be preferred among these:

```
GET /fleets/123/cars/all/vin
GET /fleets/123/cars/*/vin
GET /fleets/123/vins
GET /fleets/123/cars/vins
```

The first two preserve the hierarchy and make the controller more intuitive. The last three feels like it breaks consistency.

Are any of these preferred or is there a better way?

Comment: REST doesn't really care how you design the URIs that point to the resources as the server should feed the client with all kinds of URIs a client can invoke from the current state it is in. By providing meaningful link relation names the client can determine which URI to invoke. This is one of the steps involved in decoupling clients from APIs and make clients therefore more robust to changes while allowing servers to evolve freely without breaking clients.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly an opinion-based question. There's no one true way here, so you'll get my opinion.

I'm not sure what a `vin` is, but if it's a type of resource, and there's a collection of `vins` as a child of a `fleet` resource, I would expect it to live here:

```
GET /fleets/123/vins
```

This communicates to me a `vin` is not a subordinate of a car. It's its own thing and I'm getting all vins for a specific fleet.

The fact that a `vin` also exists as a subordinate of car (to me) is kind of irrelevant to this. It makes perfectly sense to me that for those, that they live here:

```
GET /fleets/123/cars/55/vin
```

Similarly, if I would model the last 2 apis as 2 functions, I would call them:

```
findVinsForFleet(fleetId: number);
findVinForCar(fleetId: number, carId: number);
```

Comment: VIN is a Vehicle Identification Number and belongs to a single car. So a fleet does not own a vin, a car does, but a fleet owns cars. I want to wildcard the cars.

Comment: Yet you _are_ asking for all VIN's in a fleet, no? Given that that's the case, I will stick with my opinion. I would definitely implement it this way. The only tweak I _might_ make is call the resource `car-vins` instead of `vins` if I worry that `vins` alone is not clear enough.